# Getting an error "'image' is a required property" while generating image variations using openai and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, http, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am getting an error "'image' is a required property" while trying to generate image variations in JavaScript. Here is my code.

```
//Function for sending http request
async function upload(formData) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", "Authorization": "Bearer" + " " + api_key}
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Success:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}
  
  // Calling it. Here I am using image data. I am sending the image but still it says 
  //that image is required

  const form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("image",imageData);
  form_data.append("n",1);
  form_data.append("size",'1024x1024');

  upload(form_data);
```

Please help me? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to HTTP itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multipart/form-data` content type has a *mandatory* `boundary` parameter which tells the recipient where each of the multiple parts begins and ends. You are omitting it so the recipient can't see the different parts and thus can't find `image` among them. You also can't know what the correct value for the `boundary` parameter is.

Under normal circumstances, `fetch` will generate the `Content-Type` header using the `FormData` object, but you are overriding it. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Do I need to omit "Content-Type or include boundary. Can you tell me how I correct this?

Comment: @WasimSafdar — You must omit `Content-Type` from the headers *you expicitly set* because you don't have enough information to correctly set the `boundary`. The `fetch` API will add the correct content-type for you.